# Why java allow to use formal type parameter in static Generic Method

Tags: java, generics

I know i can't use a type parameter in any static context of a generic class because "the static context is dependent of the type parameters and only once for all instantiations of a generic type."

```
public final class X<T>{
    private static T field; // error
    public static T getField(){return field; } // error
}
```

But I don't understand why allow to use formal type parameter in static generic method.

```
public final class X{
    public static <T> T getField(T t){ return t;} // Ok
}
```

What is difference between generic type parmeter and formal type parameter in static generic method?
May you please explain this with examples?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Formal type parameters *are* generic type parameters. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: May you please explain this[question] with examples

Comment: A method gets different type parameters every time you use it; there's no relationship between one call of a method and another call of the same method.  For fields, there's no one `T` to use; for methods, `T` is assigned at the method call site, a different `T` each place the method is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method with its own independent set of one or more **type parameters**, in which case you have a **parameterized method**, which is also referred to as a **generic method**. You can have parameterized methods in an ordinary class. Methods within a generic type definition can also have independent parameters.

You could modify the listAll() method which is **parameterized method**. Here’s how that would look:

```
public static <T> void listAll(LinkedList<T> list) 
{ 
for(T obj : list) 
{
 System.out.println(obj); 
} 
}
```

The **T** following the **public** and **static** keywords is the **type parameter** list for the generic method. Here you have only one type parameter, **T**, but you could have more. The type parameter list for a generic method always appears between angled brackets and should follow any modifiers such as **public** and **static**, as you have here, and should precede the return type.

Consider the another code snippet,

```
public <E extends T> void add(E value) 
{ 
if(root == null) { // If there’s no root node 
 root = new Node(value);          // store it in the root 
}  
else {    // Otherwise... 
add(value, root);  // add it recursively
 } 
}
```

You could also gain some advantage by using parameterized methods. Now the method has an independent parameter, **E**. The **add()** method accepts an argument of type **T**, which is the type argument. In general, you might want to allow subclasses of **T** to be added alse. The **add()** method accepts an argument of any type that is type **T**, or a subclass of **T**. This clearly adds flexibility to the use of generic class's objects. You have no need to change the body of the method in this case. All the flexibility is provided simply by the way you have defined the method parameter.

I hope my answer would be helpful for you.